# PHP pagination by tag

Tags: php, pagination

I have a database field with large text. If there is a tag inside `<!-- new page -->` I want to paginate by that tag.

What I'm trying to do is something like WordPress has, when you insert a tag such as `<!-- new page -->` I want to create a new page.

Say I have this text from a database

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elementum magna in      nulla ultrices, eu pulvinar nulla auctor. Praesent auctor ut dui vitae feugiat.

`<!-- new page -->`

Sed risus nisl, tristique sed tristique et, auctor eu augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce a ipsum ligula. Aliquam vestibulum ligula ut ligula porta gravida. Curabitur tincidunt a est vitae eleifend. Duis ullamcorper nunc sapien, quis molestie tellus ornare vel. Nullam in mi eros.

How would I make the second paragraph appear on a new page?

Something like this http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/nextpage/

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn asking question more clearly to get answers

Comment: Apologies I am not too sure how to word it. I've updated my question, hopefully that makes more sense

Comment: This question demonstrates no attempt to research or solve the problem. Please read the help section on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope my code will be helpfull :

```
<?php
//in this example :
//first you have to create a database with name : blog
// create table : article (id as primary key, name , content)
// here we supposed that in the content you have your tags <!-- new page -->
// also i supposed the name of this file as : pagination.php

//Getting the id of article:
//=========================
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    $id_article = $_GET['id'];
else
    $id_article = 1;



//Connexion to database :
//======================
$user="root";
$pass="root";
$db="blog";
$host="localhost";

$pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pass, $pdo_options);
$bdd->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


$response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='.$id_article);

$tab_content = array();

$data = $response->fetch()
echo'<div >';
    $tab_content = explode('<!-- new page -->',$data['content']);
    $count_pages = count($tab_content);
    if($count_pages){
            //in the case that you have somme tags :
            //=====================================
        echo $tab_content[$page];
        echo '<br>';
        for($i=1;$i<$count_pages;$i++)
            echo '<a href="./pagination.php?id='.$id_article.'&page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    }
    else{
            //if no tags '<!-- new page -->' in your content:
            //===============================================
        echo $data['content'];
    }
echo '</div>';

$response->closeCursor();

?>
```